# Producer and consumer details for a specific kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Want to understand how to get producer details for any specific kafka topic using java

Answer (score 1):

Kafka has no capabilities to know about producers sending to any topic. You'd need to integrate external tooling with producer certificate management and/or interceptors to emit/collect data from clients